# docker-compose with springboot and redis

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to connect a simple `springboot` app with `redis` using `docker compose`. However, I keep getting the below error.

```
    java-service_1  | 2020-11-20 10:30:54.053 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool] with root cause
java-service_1  | 
java-service_1  | java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
java-service_1  |       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
java-service_1  |       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
java-service_1  |       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
java-service_1  |       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
java-service_1  |       at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
java-service_1  |       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
java-service_1  |       at redis.clients.jedis.DefaultJedisSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultJedisSocketFactory.java:53) ~[jedis-3.3.0.jar!/:na]
java-service_1  |       at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:158) ~[jedis-3.3.0.jar!/:na]
java-service_1  |       at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:109) ~[jedis-3.3.0.jar!/:na]
```

## Config

```
@Bean
public RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration() {
    System.out.println("connecting with redis");
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration("redis", 6379);
    return redisStandaloneConfiguration;
}

@Bean
public ClientOptions clientOptions() {
    return ClientOptions.builder()
            .disconnectedBehavior(ClientOptions.DisconnectedBehavior.REJECT_COMMANDS)
            .autoReconnect(true)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory(RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration) {

    LettuceClientConfiguration configuration = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder()
            .clientOptions(clientOptions()).build();

    return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration, configuration);
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "redisTemplate")
@Primary
public RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
    StringRedisTemplate template = new StringRedisTemplate();
    template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
    return template;
}
```

## docker-compose.yml

version: '3'
services:
redis-server:
container_name: redis
image: 'redis'
ports:
- "6379:6379"
java-service:
build: .
links:
- redis-server
ports:
- "8080:8080"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think problem occurs because your application is not being able to connect to DB, because of

```
RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration 
                                    = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration("redis", 6379);
```

Now, you have used `redis` as hostname, which is not proper. You should use container name as host and make sure that both containers are on same network.

In order to make it work, you can do :

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis-server:
    container_name: redis
    image: 'redis'
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  java-service:
    build: .
    links:
      - redis-server
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

Now other containers on same network will be able to communicate to redis using `redis` as hostname.

**OR**

If you don't want to set fix container name, you use hostname property like :

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis-server:
    hostname: redis
    image: 'redis'
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  java-service:
    build: .
    links:
      - redis-server
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

Comment: I still get the same response. Edited the question with the complete error and modified config as well.

Comment: @user3310115 can you check if redis is up nd running properly, i.e. can you connect redis-client to your redis-server ?

Comment: Yes, I am able to access the redis-cli.

Comment: @user3310115 Ok. Try starting services individually but in attached mode, then check logs for failure or error. Post them here once you find it.

Comment: Actually, it was a silly mistake. I did not rebuild my springboot jar. My inital config itself worked. Once i did a mvn clean install, docker copied the new jar with the correct server name and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful for others who seeks answer for same issue
My issue resolved by removing the special character from Redis pass